# Avoiding double nat in apartment complex

Tags: firewall, routing, dd-wrt, nat

I live in an apartment complex with a great fast fiber connection to internet. The central router provides all connected apartment/computers with ip-addresses in the 10.x.x.x / 255.255.0.0 series. The gateway is 10.0.0.1.

Now, my problem is that means my neighbors computers are accessible from mine and vice versa (for example - I can control all Sonos in the neighborhood :) I can of course add another nat and have my own protected net, but there are problems with such setup.

I have a dd-wrt router and should be able to configure it to route and firewall in a proper way - but I can't figure out what setup to use? Only firewall? Set up and route from another subnet? Accept double nat?

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: What would be the best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't many options here. You could create another subnet without NAT; the setup on your DD-WRT would be essentially the same except without NAT enabled.

However, you would need configuration access on the *main* router – it needs to be taught a route for your subnet, otherwise it'd just try to send packets towards the WAN.

- Let's say your DD-WRT has the IP address `10.0.33.978/16` on the "WAN" side, and `192.168.1.1/24` on the "LAN" side. The main router would need this route:

  ```
  192.168.1.0/24 via 10.0.33.978
  ```

If you cannot do that, check whether DD-WRT supports a "bridge firewall" mode, which would let you remain in the same subnet but at least block untrusted incoming connections.

*(No, leaving it in router mode but configuring both sides for 10.0.0.0/16 is not going to work.)*